# What is __attribute__((reqd_work_group_size(X, Y, Z))) used for?

Tags: opencl

I am a new OpenCL programmer, and I am confused about how to set the workgroup size.  Which is the correct way to set the workgroup size:

1. setting local_work_size parameter in `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` in host code.
2. using `__attribute__((reqd_work_group_size(X, Y, Z)))` in kernel code.
3. using both.
4. something else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ensures that the right workgroup size is passed in.  Typically, the necessary size of local memory is a function of the workgroup size. E.g. working on a 16x16 tile of an image.

E.g. one can write:

```
__attribute__((reqd_work_group_size(16, 16, 1)))
kernel foo void(...) {
   local float tile[16][16]; // compiler allocates local memory
   ...
}
```

The compiler allocates the local memory and we needn't pass it in as an explicit argument. However, we need to ensure that the workgroup size matches that assumption. This attribute does exactly that.

Comment: So setting workgroup size is hard code, right? Are there anyway to set workgroup size dynamically?

Comment: you could pass it in at kernel compile time as a #define (and either on the fly, or beforehand, compile for various predefined sizes and swap at runtime), but as far as I'm aware you can't have a true dynamically sized local array

Comment: You can pass in a local buffer as a kernel argument and use `clSetKernelArg` to var the size when you enqueue the NDRange. That makes it dynamic between NDRanges.